# (GAMS) how to use subsets when loading gdx-file?

Tags: gams-math

I don't think it's a complex problem, but I searched for a long time and didn't find a solution  :/
I want to load data from a gdx-file and use set-items and subsets as identifiers (in the example below: different value for d and e and same value for all local modes).
The gdx-file is written correctly, but the parameter includes only the value for set-items. How can I get GAMS to assign the value to all items of the according subset?
I hope, the problem is clear and there is an easy solution. Thanks in advance!

Code (simplified):

```
sets 

mode /a, b, c, d, e/

local_mode(mode) /a, b, c/
;

parameter par_consumption_per_km(year, mode);

$LOAD par_consumption_per_km;
```

Comment: It is not really clear to me, what you mean. You say, "the gdx-file is written correctly" So what is in the file for par_consumption_per_km, what do you get for that parameter after loading it, and how is it different from what you expect? BTW: You should not have a semicolon at the end of the $load line.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late answer. I was not notified about your post. par_consumption_per_km contains both values that are labeled as normal set items (a, b, c etc) and as "local_mode". I want GAMS to understand that the value labeled as "local_mode" stands for set-items a, b and c. Finally it's just a method to organize the input-file more efficiently. As our model is based on very complex input-files, this would help a lot :)

Comment: So is it that after loading par_consumption_per_km contain values for all elements of mode (a, b, c, d and e) but you just want the values for the items in local_mode (just a, b, c)?

Comment: Sorry, I explained it misleadingly. In the parameter are only the elements, which were marked directly as mode. The elements, which i imported with the label local-mode (and which are correctly in the gdx) are not written into the parameter. So GAMS does not assign the subset to the parameter, although it's a subset of mode.

Comment: Could you share the minimal example including the data file to reproduce this? That should help to understand your problem.